# Processing form's element(s) in JSP

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a HTML form in JSP page, and in the  I have a JavaScript validation. The user must enter one field: name or id or year, and a java file will search the student in database by name or by id or by year. The JavaScript alerts when no field is filled and performs the **action** if one field is filled.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Student to search into database</title>

<script language="javascript">
function validate2(objForm){

int k = 0;
if(objForm.name.value.length==0){
objForm.name.focus();
k++;
}

if(objForm.year.value.length==0){
objForm.year.focus();
k++;
}

if(objForm.id.value.length==0){
objForm.year.focus();
k++;
}

if(k == 0){
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>


</head>
<body bgcolor=#ADD8E6><center>

<form action="FoundStudents.jsp" method="post" name="entry2" onSubmit="validate2(this)">
<input type="hidden" value="list" name="seek_stud">
```

...........................................................................................

The problem is I want to process the parameter which I receive in FoundStudents.jsp: If I get the year, I look in DB which student(s) are in that year and display all that student(s)' data(do that in a java file). How could I do that in FoundStudents.Jsp without checking again which field is filled(I've done that in JavaScript from **SearchStudent.jsp**). I mean the FoundStudents.jsp calls a method in the java file for searching and displaying.

I tried by now with the **input hidden** that worked, but that is for more forms. I have only 1.

**FoundStudent.jsp**

```
<%@page import="stud.diploma.students.StudentsManager"%>
<%@page import="stud.diploma.students.Student"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="stud.diploma.database.ConnectionsManager"%>

<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*, java.lang.*" %>

<%
Student search = null;
if(request.getParameter("seek_stud") != null){

//reading params from the SearchStudent form
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String year_prime = request.getParameter("year");
int year, id;

try{
year = Integer.parseInt(year_prime);
}catch(Exception e1){
year = 0; 
}

String id_prime = request.getParameter("id");
try{
id = Integer.parseInt("id");
}catch(Exception e2){
id = 0;
}


if(name.length() != 0){
search = StudentsManager.getInstance().studByName(name);
}

if(year > 0){
search = StudentsManager.getInstance().studByYear(year);
}

if(id > 0){
search = StudentsManager.getInstance().studById(id);
} 

if(search != null){
%>

<html>
<body bgcolor=#4AA02C>
<center>
<h2>Student's data</h2>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="8" bgcolor= #EBDDE2> 
<tr>
<td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>ID</b></td>
<td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>Name</b></td>
<td bgcolor= #FF9966><b>Year</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><%= search.getId()%></td>
<td><%= search.getName()%></td>
<td><%= search.getYear()%></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<%}else{%>

<%
String redirectURL = "MainMenu.html";
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>

<%}%>
<%}%>
```

This **FoundStudent.jsp** is for the version of multiple forms (using hidden input) that worked. (the javascript test was just a little bit different, I typed it insted of what I had in the beginning)

It searched by name and by year only. Didn't search by ID (I had exception here `<td><%= search.getId()%></td>` I'm still trying to see how to deal with it. ID is a AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)

Lines like : `search = StudentsManager.getInstance().studByName(name);` 
**Search** is a Student type object. (Object Student is creaded in a java file)

**StudentsManager** is a java class that receives calls to it's methods from JSP. getInstance() creates an instance of StudentsManager. Method **studByName(name)** receives the parameter **name** from the form and searches it in the database.

Comment: Can post What have you tried in "FoundStudent.jsp" and It is not good practice to write JAVA code in JSP. JSP should only be used for presentation layer

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the (java)script to:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function validateSea(){
                if(document.entry2.name.value != ''){
                    return true;
                }

                else
                    if(document.entry2.year.value != ''){
                       return true;
                    }

                alert('Please fill one field.');
                return false;   
             }
          </script>

        </head>
```

which is for 1 form. I'm not sure if I did the correct thing, but in FoundStudents.jsp, where I receive the parameters of the form, I test:

```
if((request.getParameter("year") != null)||(request.getParameter("name") != null)){

        //reading params from the SearchStudent form
................}
```

It works this way.